# How to use multiple update query for single table on same store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have stored procedure which has

1) update query and I want to add the

2) update query in the same store procedure. Is that possible that I can use the below code? or Can anyone help me how can I use multiple update query for the same table?

```
USE [Databse]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Tableupdate]    
Script Date: 5/19/2017 8:12:11 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Tableupdate]
@IncomeID int,
@MemberID int,
@ParticipantID int,
@IncomeTypeID int,
@PaymentFrequencyTypeID int,
@Employer varchar(max),
@Occupation varchar(max),
@TypeOfBusiness varchar(max),
@GrossAmount decimal(18,2),
@Verified bit
AS
BEGIN
1)UPDATE Table SET
    MemberID=@MemberID,
    ParticipantID=@ParticipantID,
    IncomeTypeID=@IncomeTypeID,
    PaymentFrequencyTypeID=@PaymentFrequencyTypeID,
    Employer=@Employer,
    Occupation=@Occupation,
    TypeOfBusiness=@TypeOfBusiness,
    GrossAmount=@GrossAmount,
    Verified=@Verified 
WHERE IncomeID=@IncomeID

2)Update table set ParticipantID = @ParticipantID where MemberID = @MemberID
END
```

Comment: Just put a semicolon after your first query to separate the statements.

Comment: Did you try it? Of course you can have a procedure execute multiple update statements. Would be pretty useless if it couldn't. Be careful tagging as mysql <> sql server. And you should also read this. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible, you can set as many UPDATE statements in their as you want.

Do note that your last update statement will overwrite your first update statements, if the same records are touched.

Best practice would be to end each statement with a semicolon e.g. ';').

```
USE [Databse]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Tableupdate]    
Script Date: 5/19/2017 8:12:11 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Tableupdate]
@IncomeID int,
@MemberID int,
@ParticipantID int,
@IncomeTypeID int,
@PaymentFrequencyTypeID int,
@Employer varchar(max),
@Occupation varchar(max),
@TypeOfBusiness varchar(max),
@GrossAmount decimal(18,2),
@Verified bit,
@run_proc int
AS
BEGIN
IF(@run_proc = 1)
BEGIN
PRINT 'Running Update 1';
UPDATE Table SET
    MemberID=@MemberID,
    ParticipantID=@ParticipantID,
    IncomeTypeID=@IncomeTypeID,
    PaymentFrequencyTypeID=@PaymentFrequencyTypeID,
    Employer=@Employer,
    Occupation=@Occupation,
    TypeOfBusiness=@TypeOfBusiness,
    GrossAmount=@GrossAmount,
    Verified=@Verified 
WHERE IncomeID=@IncomeID;
END

ELSE IF(@run_proc = 2) BEGIN
    PRINT 'Running Update 2';
    Update table set ParticipantID = @ParticipantID where MemberID = @MemberID  
END

END
```

Comment: How can i use it? it will run both the query when i call the stored procedure. I just want to run the 2) query.

Comment: If you only want to run one of the 2 queries, you can add a parameter, and run either one of the queries depending on the parameter's value.. though you might be better of with 2 separate procedures. I will update the code.